# How do I integrate Bootstrap3 into Symfony3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twig, symfony

I looked everywhere but I can't find a documentation on how to apply bootstrap styles to Symfony, or twig to be precise.

Many answers are [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012156/bootstrap-form-theme-in-symfony-3-1) as they are mostly about Symfony 2.x with bootstrap3.

For reference, I am trying to add a style to

```
{{ form_start(form))}}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle
And replacing some parts of form layout ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html , https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig ) dependind on using bootstrap elements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172660/bootstrap-3-not-working-in-symfony3 Did you check this one ?

Comment: Did you check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172660/bootstrap-3-not-working-in-symfony3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 not working in Symfony3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172660/bootstrap-3-not-working-in-symfony3)

Comment: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme

Comment: Just add `bootstrap.min.css` in the `<head>` section of your page, and `jquery.min.js` + `bootstrap.min.js` in the `<body>` section, at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Since Symfony 2.6, Bootstrap is included in Symfony without the need for a specific bundle, [as announced in this news](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme), and explained [in the doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#twig).

There are 2 layouts available, the normal layout and the horizontal one.

To apply it everywhere:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'
        # - 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig'
```

Or only for specific forms, add this at the top of the corresponding Twig files:

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
{# {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %} #}
```